# What is the function of Tomcat manage page when I am developing web application on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to develop a web application on Eclipse. So I configured Tomcat 8 into Eclipse on Mac. However, after the configuration of Tomcat, I found that only a few files existing in the server folder in the workspace of Eclipse. There are some other files in the Tomcat installation directory like webapps. Are they useful, like Tomcat manager page?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse WTP basically leaves your Tomcat installation untouched. For each server that you configure on the server view a folder under the servers project is created. When you start a server the files in its server directory are applied as an overlay to the standard tomcat. All server instance specific parts end up there and the base installation stays untouched.

If you are for instance always working with the same DB then you may want to add the DB driver to the Tomcat base installation. Other than that you probably don't want to mess with that folder and instead configure everything only per server instance.

The tomcat manager application can be useful especially when the server is running on a remote machine to which the access is difficult. Then you can build a WAR locally and deploy it via your browser / the manager app (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_using_the_Tomcat_Manager). If the tomcat is only started from within your eclipse and you are using dynamic web projects to deploy applications on the server then the manager app is likely not too interesting. It provides some monitoring features though.

(http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! I just started to study JSP. There are so much to learn.

Comment: If you have a choice then I would rather spend time on learning HTML5 for instance with jQuery, AngularJS or another popular framework. JSP does not seem a very future proof technology these days, at least to me.